# Is there any way for a User in SignalR to know in which group he belongs to from the client side?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

*Note: This is a security related question.*

I am putting users in groups, which the name are moderately sensitive (database object ids).

I am sending messages to groups from the server side, never from client (that's why putting db object ids in the group's names was not a problem for me).

From my understanding, I am assuming that SignalR is managing groups deep inside its core, and communicate only with each Connections, but I am not sure.

**So my questions are:**

Does the groups name are well hidden from client?

Or is it possible for a User (from the client side), to discover in which Group(s) he belongs to? (and then potentially discover sensitive data if developer was assuming groups names where hidden/inaccessible)

Answer (score 0):

Group names would only be exposed if you passed them to the client.

From the server side, SignalR has no API to maintain or expose this. You can maintain your own group names, thus any exposure would come from your own doing.

As far as security goes, that should be handled outside of SignalR.

You can however check out using roles to help if you need to restrict on specific methods such as ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/)): 
`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`
public class AdminAuthHub : Hub
`{`
}